# What are the best practices on storing cross-compiled libs?

Tags: libraries, cross-compilation

I have a project I want to cross compile (as well as native).

I've installed my cross compiler under `/opt/x-compiler/arm32/` and I also add some dependencies I have under `/opt/lib/arm32/`.

The dependencies are both dinamically likned libs (.SO) and statically linked libs (.a).

I used to have a script that would download everything into my working dir, but that would cause a mess + take a long time (when I git clean / create a new repo), so I copied it once to `/opt` and now I just point my build system to the updated locations.

Is the location I chose good? What makes a location for such things good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

> What makes a location for such things good or bad?

Maintenance.

You decide on a location. Use it. Project is finished. In a year, you start a new similar project. Do you remember where you put your libraries?

Your colleague is starting a similar project. Can you share your libraries?

You left the company, a new hire is starting a similar project - will he find these libraries?